# Python - Algorithm to compute k fractions of form 1/r summing up to 1

Tags: python, algorithm, fractions

I have the code already figured out and have found a way to get around the problem that for `k > 6` the largest denominator is very large. But when my code adds up for example

```
1/float(2) + 1/float(3) + 1/float(7) + 1/float(42)
```

`python` says that it is not equal to `1`, but it should be. Why does `python` recognize other sums as being equal to `1` but not this one?

Comment: Additional info when using fp-math: equality-checks usually follow the approach of [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html).

Comment: Egyptian fractions are fun. The simple way to work with them in Python is to use the fractions module.

Comment: FWIW, here are some lists I've found, which you may find useful in testing your code. These are lists of the given length of minimum highest denominator (with no repeated fractions): 6 [2, 3, 15, 18, 35, 63], 7 [2, 3, 15, 28, 35, 44, 77], 8 [2, 4, 6, 20, 58, 130, 174, 377]. I'm pretty sure 6 & 7 are correct, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's a better solution to 8.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are asking for floating point arithmetic, and when the roundoff errors add up, you'll get wrong answers.

Use the https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html module to get real fractions and roundoff issues should disappear for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be **extremely careful** when **hard-comparing** any **decimal values**. Computer **don't provide unlimited precision**, thus it could be that your argument adds up to something like `0.99999998` instead of `1`. Then the comparison might **fail**.

Thus you should always compare corresponding to an allowed difference of `delta`, like `1 - 0.99999998 < delta` where `delta = 0.0001` or something like that.